# Can someone tell me if I have installed ionic correctly? None of the commands I use works?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, putty, ionic-framework

I have downloaded node.js and I am using a azure virtual machine through putty, I'm pretty sure I installed everything correctly. I installed ionic,

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

and then I tryed to create a file.,

```
ionic start todo blank
```

But the it just skips  to the next line and nothing happens? when I try list the 
contents of the file it says it does not exist?

```
cd todo && ls
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Did you fallowed the tutorial? http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/

Comment: I'm using Java 7, would that make a difference?

Comment: Idk... you should remake the process fallowing every instruction that the video shows.

Answer (score 0):

If you just **add the type into the fil**e created ,it should then show you the contents.like:

**$ ionic start todo blank --type ionic1**

later you can check the contents using the command:

**$ cd todo && ls**

I guess this should do the work, let me know if you have anymore doubts.
You can even go through the [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html) for more about installation.